# How to limit changes to `sbt run` and `sbt test` tasks?

Tags: sbt

I'm puzzled by `sbt` tool. I would like to define two Java options, one for `sbt run` target and another for `sbt test` target. These options require forking the VM, which I would not like to happen for other commands (such as `compile`, `update`).

How to define this in the `build.sbt` elegantly?

- what's the role of the `Compile` thing? What about `Test`?
- how to declare `fork` only once, so that it would apply to both `sbt run` and `sbt test`?

I've been using `sbt` for a few years, now. Read the documents. Something like this still escapes me. *sigh*

```
fork in run := true

javaOptions in (Compile,run) ++= Seq(
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/debug.conf"
)

fork in test := true

javaOptions in (Test,test) ++= Seq(
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/debug-test.conf"
)
```

Using `sbt` 0.13.8

Comment: Are you on a multi-project project? If yes, then the setting you defined above will just be defined for the "Root" project and not for any of the sub-projects.

Comment: No, it's a single build.sbt based project. I think my confusion is about the `(Compile, run)` kind of syntax - the various "axes" that sbt allow to be used. The need itself went away though, for unrelated reasons I needed to avoid forking in `test` altogether, and I now override `config.file` from the outer build system that launches sbt.

Comment: Let me try to give an answer. I would love to hear your comments to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to specify that you only want to fork() on `sbt run` and not on other executions of `run` (e.g., on `sbt test:run`) then you need to use the Configuration scope together with the task. That is:

```
fork in (Compile,run) := true
```

If you had the following:

```
fork in run := true
```

It will fork all run tasks, including `test:run` etc.

Now, if you had this:

```
fork := true
```

It will fork() all the fork-able task in all scopes.

---

Coming back to your questions, you can think of the (Compile, run) and (Test, run) etc. as instances of `(Configuration,task)` scope. You should use this construct when you want to narrow down the scope of a particular setting down to the task of a specific configuration: Compile, Run, Test, or any custom one you may have.

In your `.sbt` file I think the right thing to do is:

```
fork in (Compile,run) := true

javaOptions in (Compile,run) ++= Seq(
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/debug.conf"
)

fork in (Test,test) := true

javaOptions in (Test,test) ++= Seq(
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/debug-test.conf"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @marios Is there any case where one would use `(Compile,test)` or alternatively `(Test,run)`? I cannot see any.

Comment: `(Test,run)` would make sense if you have runnable classes inside your `test` subfolder. There might be cases where that is useful ... Now about `(Compile,test)`, when I do `show compile:test` on SBT interactive, it says "No such setting/task". Since this particular task doesn't seem to be useful, maybe is not implemented? If I had to speculate, maybe if you have test code inside your normal `src` folder, then this could execute those tests. Maybe ...